# A smooth function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ agrees with an analytic function on a bounded infinite set

Tags: real-analysis, smoothness, analytic-functions

Fix a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Do there exist real numbers $a<b$, an infinite set $S\subset (a, b)$ and an analytic function $g$ defined on $(a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f|_S=g|_S$?

If $g$ is only required to be defined on $(a, b)$ the question has a positive answer. In fact, we can take any $(a, b)$ we like and set $g=f(a)+\mathrm{sin}(\frac{1}{x-a})$.

We can not require $g$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ since we can take $f(x)=\mathrm{exp}(-\frac{1}{|x|})$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then by the pigeonhole principle $S$ must contain infinitely many positive numbers or infinitely many negative numbers; in either case $g$ does not extend to $\mathbb{R}$. Coincidentally, this shows that an arbitrary $(a, b)$ won't do in the original problem.

Comment: The following link might answer your question: https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194815/mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148

Comment: Do you mean an open interval or an open set? In the former case, if 0 and 1 are limit points of $S$, that may be supposed to be true, we must take $U=(0,1)$.

Comment: I think it is true, and you can choose a and b, and f may be just continuous. In case  (a,b) is the whole real line, g can be taken entire.

Comment: The latter because any continuous function from **R** to **R** can be uniformly approximated by an entire real analytic function. So any $g$ with uniform distance less than 1/2 from $f+\sin x$ coincides with f in an infinite set. The case of a general interval  (a,b) follows composing with an analytic diffeo from (a,b) to **R**.

Comment: Following Pietro Majer's comment: approximate your $f$ by a polynomial $P$ so that $|f(x) - P(x)| < 1$ for $x \in (a, b)$, and set $g(x) = P(x) + \sin(\frac{1}{x-a})$. A perhaps more interesting question would ask for $g$ analytic in a larger interval $(a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$.

Comment: For the mentioned density fact: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26243/asymptotic-approximation-of-x-alpha-by-entire-functions/26290#26290

Comment: (indeed the case $(a,b)=\mathbb{R}$ is somehow more interesting)

Comment: @PietroMajer can't you just take $S=\mathbb{Z}$ in that case?

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327540) might be useful. If $f(x)$ can be sampled on some infinite $S \subset (a,b)$ such that the Nevanlinna-Pick condition (on a complex disc of appropriate diameter) is satisfied gives you a positive answer, by resorting to complex analytic interpolation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your edit. If $f$ is defined as you describe, it has values in $[0,1]$, so $g(x)=\sin(x)$ coincides with $f$ on an infinite set.

Comment: Also, if you just want some infinite set, $x\mapsto f(a)+sin(\frac1{x-a})$ works just as well, the polynomial $P$ is superfluous.

Comment: @PierrePC you are correct about the irrelevance of $P$

Comment: @PierrePC but there is no bounded infinite set on which they coincide. I think if two analytic functions coincide on a bounded infinite set they are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**, not necessarily.

Let $f$ be any smooth function such that the Taylor series of $f$ about any point $p$ has zero radius of convergence; see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/81479/108637) for an explicit example.

Suppose that $g$ is a smooth function such that for some sequence $(x_n)$ convergent to $p$ (and such that $x_n \ne p$) we have $f(x_n) = g(x_n)$. It is rather easy to see that $f^{(k)}(p) = g^{(k)}(p)$ for every $k \geqslant 0$, and hence the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$ about $p$ coincide. In particular, the Taylor series of $g$ about $p$ has zero radius of convergence, and consequently $g$ is not real-analytic at $p$.

Comment: @PierrePC: Right, thanks. I updated the reference.